# LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method and this method cannot be translated into a store expression

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, entity-framework, linq-to-sql

```
var ps = dbContext.SplLedgers.Select(p => new SplLedgerModel
            {
                Name = p.Name,
                VoucherType = Convert.ToString(((JIMS.VoucherTypes)p.VoucherType))
        });
```

I am getting the following exception, whats wrong with the code.

JIMS.VoucherType is an enum

```
+       $exception  {"LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToString(System.Object)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression."}    System.Exception {System.NotSupportedException}
```

Comment: Good link to discussion on this matter: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/adodotnetentityframework/thread/19a33909-c532-419b-a533-57e431c0b30b

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your code is basically trying to find the Convert.ToString() method in the DB and understandably failing.

You can get around it, for example by making sure the query executes before the select, e.g.

```
var ps = dbContext.SplLedgers.Select(p => new  
    { 
         Name = p.Name, 
         VoucherType = p.VoucherType
    }).ToList().Select(p => new SplLedgerModel( 
    { 
         Name = p.Name, 
         VoucherType = Convert.ToString(((JIMS.VoucherTypes)p.VoucherType)) 
    });
```

Comment: Has the disadvantage of retrieving all columns of SplLedgers, rather than just Name and VoucherType (which may or may not be significant).

Comment: Fair point, so could be refined as above

Comment: But when  i tried to bind this data to my datagrid using CollectionViewSource... there are rows but the content is not visible.

Comment: I think that is nothing to do with the original question, so you should raise another question for this please.